# Unity Get the Amount a certain field is "filled"

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, area, bounds

so as you probably see in the first picture I have this area marked by the black Walls.

The task is to fill this area, the result is the orange area + the black wall underneath it. Now I would like to track how much of the field is covered by the orange field.

As you can see I tried by creating a PolygonCollider of all the CornerPoints of the Field, getting the bounds.size of it and then doing the same with the orange field and kind of subtracting them.

When I do this with a recangular area it is working perfectly fine, like seen in the second picture, why is it dont working properly with a non rectangular area?

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: Not quite sure about it, but let me raise a doubt. Bounds.size should give the AABB of the object, that is always the minimal enclosing box. So, it will not represent the exact volume of the sphere. Can you calculate the volume of the sphere with other methods?

Answer (score 0):

bounds gives an axis aligned bounding box that fully encloses the collider. In general case, the area (or volume) of the bounding box is not equal to the area of the enclosed polygon.

Comment: oh, I see, so there is no way to get the area(volume) of a polygon collider2D?

Comment: You can calculate the area from the polygon points like in https://answers.unity.com/questions/684909/how-to-calculate-the-surface-area-of-a-irregular-p.html